# Elasticsearch term query for words contain another word

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, nosql

My mapping is:

```
  "alarmName" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "norms" : {
      "enabled" : false
    },
    "analyzer" : "lowercase_analyzer"
  }
```

and setting is:

```
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "lowercase_analyzer" : {
          "filter" : [ "lowercase" ],
          "tokenizer" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
```

I index some events with alarmName = "pro profile".

but when i query with:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "term" : {
      "alarmName" : "pro profile"
    }
  }
}
```

i get nothing.
But with this query:

```
{ 
  "size" : 0, 
  "aggs" : { 
    "alarms" : { 
      "terms" : { 
        "field" : "alarmName", 
        "size" : 100 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this result:

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 175023,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "alarms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "multi app profile",
          "doc_count": 166733
        },
        {
          "key": "not mac profile",
          "doc_count": 3755
        },
        {
          "key": "port profile",
          "doc_count": 1579
        },
        {
          "key": "not ip profile",
          "doc_count": 932
        },
        {
          "key": "not pro  profile",
          "doc_count": 543
        },
        {
          "key": "not app profile",
          "doc_count": 507
        },
        {
          "key": "app profile",
          "doc_count": 370
        },
        {
          "key": "mac profile",
          "doc_count": 365
        },
        {
          "key": "ip profile",
          "doc_count": 114
        },
        {
          "key": "pro  profile",
          "doc_count": 94
        },
        {
          "key": "not port profile",
          "doc_count": 31
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

for all other words with space every things are OK, but for this words(`pro profile`) i have this problem.
This is a bug?
This is for that profile contains pro?

Comment: can you paste the output of this aggs query here - { "aggs" : { "alarms" : { "terms" : { "field" : "alarmName" }}}}

Comment: @VineethMohan i edited the question with your query

Comment: There is only one space between pro and profile in your query while there are two in your data according to the aggregation result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i should search for pro profile (with 2 space) not pro profile (1 space)

that was my mistake